# Unable to recover from the build error in the GNOME gftp application

Tags: git, gnome, m4

```
root@chandrasekar-Calpella:/home/chandrasekar/gftp# ./autogen.sh --prefix=$(pwd)
gettextize -c --intl -f
gettextize: warning: the option '--intl' is deprecated and will be removed

configure.in:89: warning: macro `AM_PATH_GLIB' not found in library
configure.in:205: warning: macro `AM_PATH_GTK' not found in library

autoconf
configure.in:89: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PATH_GLIB
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.in:205: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PATH_GTK

./configure: line 7229: syntax error near unexpected token `1.2.3,'
./configure: line 7229: `  AM_PATH_GLIB(1.2.3, , as_fn_error $? "gFTP needs GLIB 1.2.3 or higher" "$LINENO" 5)'
```

After googling found that need to install the glibc and gtk packages. So tried to install, but already the packages are installed. So ran the aclocal to generate the *.m4, but still not able to build the GNOME gftp application which is downloaded from the GIT repository. Please help in addressing the issue so that i can build and start contributing to GNOME gftp.

Answer (score 1):

`Gftp` is looking for two macros `AM_PATH_GLIB` and `AM_PATH_GTK` when it wants to compile. Unfortunately, these are not available. On my system (Debian testing) I found that there instead existed two macros `AM_PATH_GLIB_2_0` and `AM_PATH_GTK_2_0` in `/usr/share/aclocal`.

Now, replacing `AM_PATH_GLIB` with `AM_PATH_GLIB_2_0` and `AM_PATH_GTK` with `AM_PATH_GTK_2_0` in `configure.in` in the `gftp` source made it get past these problems.

I also got an error saying that support for automatic `de-ANSI-fication` support had been removed. I got past this by commenting out `AM_C_PROTOTYPES` in configure.in. With these changes `gftp` compiled successfully for me.

Comment: Just for the record, `AM_PATH_GLIB` is provided by `GLib` 1.0 and `AM_PATH_GTK` is provided by `GTK` 1.0. You successfully tricked `gftp` into building against the 2.0 versions but for old software this kind of hack won't always work.